# "1, 2, 3, 4, that’s it."

Tags: word-usage, phrases, parts-of-speech, numbers

In the sentence "1, 2, 3, 4, that’s it.", what parts of speech would the phrase "1, 2, 3, 4" be?

I asked that because I was imagining or seeing that I would just say '1,2,3,4' before I  finish doing something or before I say 'that’s it'

so I probably wanted to know what is '1,2,3,4' when I say '1, 2, 3, 4, that’s it.' or what parts of speech is '1, 2, 3, 4'

And I was wondering what parts of speech the phrase "1, 2, 3, 4" would be because I was trying to analyze it or understand it and I think I wasn’t understanding it or analyzing it.

And I think I wanted to see if "1, 2, 3, 4" is a parts of speech.

Comment: It's not a part of speech. Counting doesn't make a sentence, just like saying "la la la la" doesn't make a sentence.

Comment: If it isn’t a part of speech, what might "1,2,3,4" be?

Comment: Another way of looking at is this -- "One, two, three, four..." are adjectives. This is because the speaker is counting *something*, and that part is often left out. You could write the sentence as "One (something), two (somethings)...-- that's it." Does that help?

Comment: This is a good question, so I'm upvoting it. I'm not 100% sure of my answer, that's why I'm putting it as a comment.

Comment: I thank you for upvoting my question because I think some people be downvoting some questions and some ignore my questions.

Comment: I was thinking numbers can also be nouns, pronouns, and determiners and I was thinking the person was saying or counting "1,2,3,4" when they said "1,2,3,4 that's it".

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in your sentence are not a part of speech in the English language. Parts of speech (*nouns, pronouns, adjective, verb, adverb, preposition, conjunction, interjection, and articles*) are used for words.

The numbers in a sentence may be ordinal (represent rank or order of things), temporal (represent time), or nominal (identify something as in your sentence "1,2,3,4, that's it.").

Some idioms and phrases may also contain numbers that have special meanings. For instance,

- Easy as 1-2-3 (simple and straightforward).
- At sixes and sevens (total confusion or disarray).
- Behind the eight ball (mentally struggling or unable to keep up with a situation).
- A picture is worth a thousand words (pictures convey more information than words).
- A bunch of fives (punch someone).
- Back to square one (back to where one started).

Comment: I'm not so sure... "one" is a word, and in (for example) "one apple," it _is_ a part of speech. Also "behind the eight ball" does not mean "in a precarious situation," it means struggling or unable to mentally keep up with a situation.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the correction. I have edited my answer accordingly. Numbers can be part of speech one apple, one is a part of speech. Correct me if I am wrong, it's adjective,  right?

Comment: If numbers aren't parts of speech, what are numbers?

Comment: Numbers are numerical digits that represent quantities.

Comment: I think numbers might be parts of speech, determiners, nouns, pronouns, and adjectives also. Do you think that? Or what do you think about that?

Comment: Yes you are right to an extent. Numbers can be adjective if placed before a noun. For instance, one table. But in the sentence of OP numbers are not part of a speech. It depends on the context.

Comment: I've done a bit of research and found that numbers can also be pronouns, nouns, and determiners. More about it here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296633/can-numbers-be-treated-as-nouns

Answer (score 0):

**It's likely that the numbers are nouns.** But it depends on context.

For example:

> "What numbers have you seen?"

> "1, 2, 3, 4 and that's it."

The four numbers you have seen are listed. They are the things you have seen, so they are nouns.

To give any more information you would have to give us more information about the sentence.

Comment: What I meant was that someone would just say '1,2,3,4' before they finish doing something or before they say 'that’s it' so I probably wanted to know what is '1,2,3,4' or what parts of speech is '1, 2, 3, 4'

Comment: @user6779864 If you meant that please edit your question to say so.